# Environment Variables edit by VB script

Tags: vbscript

I want to create VB script that add the Variable name & Variable value in the Environment 
Variables window (in the XP sys) ,

For example (how to add “OS” and “Windows_NT\other “ )
 in the Environment Variables 
window by VB script? and Only in case if they not exists?

Variable name=OS

Variable value=Windows_NT\other

Example of manual procedure (XP) :

```
 Click on my computer --> properties --> advanced --> Environment Variables --> new 

 insert  OS                       in Variable name
 insett  Windows_NT\other         in Variable value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick Google search turned up this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_environment.php

I don't like posting only a link as an answer but it pretty much says it all I think.